# How do I get all the values of an array without having to manually access to each key?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to know how I can get all the values of an array without having to manually access to each key to then get the value.

That is, I have this arrangement.

```
$user = [ "Id" => 123, "Name" => "Dave", "Age" => 25, "Country" => "US"];
```

I want to get the values 123, "Dave," 25, "US".

Comment: Its kinda hard to understand what you are asking for... What do you mean with manually access the keys to get the value? What do you wish to do instead?

Comment: anything wrong with `implode`? ie: `implode(',',$user);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a function that does exactly what you need, which is [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) Return all the values of an array.

```
// e.g.
$user = [
    "id"   => 123,
    "name" => "Dave",
    "age"  => 25,
    "country" => "US"
  ];

print_r(array_values($user));
```

Result

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => Dave
        [2] => 25
        [3] => US
    )
```

### NOTE:

But beware of [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) values because if any value of the array is **TRUE**, [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) it will transform to 1 and if the value is **FALSE** will not return anything (it has the same behavior as the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function)

Comment: Or simply you can do `echo implode(",", $user);`

Answer (score 0):

YOu can get all the values without the keys and then use implode to make it into a single string

```
$array = array_values($user);
var_dump($array);
```

you will get

`array(4) { 
[0]=> int(123) 
[1]=> string(4) "Dave" 
[2]=> int(25) 
[3]=> string(2) "US" }`

If you want it as a string use

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $user);
echo $comma_separated;
```

Result will be

```
123,Dave,25,US
```

Comment: In that case then you don't need **array_values**, you can do simply: `echo implode(",", $user);`